# 2 dimensional array with seats by using class

Tags: arrays, class, oop

I wanted to create an array by using class at the same time which it must be produced as below:

```
  Airline A          Airline B          Airline C

1 0 0 0 0 0        1 0 0 0 0 0        1 0 0 0 0 0

-----------        -----------        -----------

2 0 0 0 0 0        2 0 0 0 0 0        2 0 0 0 0 0 

3 0 0 0 0 0        3 0 0 0 0 0        3 0 0 0 0 0 

4 0 0 0 0 0        4 0 0 0 0 0        4 0 0 0 0 0 

5 0 0 0 0 0        5 0 0 0 0 0        5 0 0 0 0 0
```

How can I create this?

Comment: Does it have to be a two-dimensional array, or will a 1-dimensional array work?